# Cannot Backup my CiviCRM DataBase due to an Unexpected Error

Tags: backups

I use the Backup & Migrate Drupal Module

I realize that I have never had my CiviCRM DB saved, though it is mentionned in the Sources Backup configuration list.

I have only one Settings Profile, which only contains "Default Settings" / "Default DataBase" (which I understand to be the Drupal DB).

If I want to "override" the existing Setting or "Create a New Profile", I get the following message :

"The Web site has encountered an unexpected error ; please try later".

Is there any expectable reason ?

(Currently in Drupal 7.54)

--------------------------- Edited 04/19/2017

I have submitted the problem to CiviHosting : this is their answer :

*"I enabled logging for your site and the error is this:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'XXXXX'@'' (using
password: YES) in backup_migrate_source_db->_get_db_connection() (line 213 of
/home/XXXXX/www/www/sites/all/modules/backup_migrate/includes/sources.db.inc).
which I do not understand as the XXXXX has access to both the CiviCRM and the
Drupal database."*

Comment: Can you check your apache server logs for more information?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer : how can I check the server logs (I am not a developper, but my hoster provides a cpanel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have deleted my CiviCRM DB from the Settings Sources, then recreated it, and it seems to work now.

I may have entered bad credentials, but the error message is not very explanatory.